# What percentage of your credit card limit should you use

Tags: credit-card, credit-score, credit-report, credit-history, credit-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the optimal ratio of used credit to credit limit for your credit score?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/what-is-the-optimal-ratio-of-used-credit-to-credit-limit-for-your-credit-score)
>   [Does length of credit history or percent of credit used count for more?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/14149/does-length-of-credit-history-or-percent-of-credit-used-count-for-more)

I just read this [article](http://www.creditcardchaser.com/what-percentage-of-your-credit-card-limit-should-you-use/) and wondering how true it is.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/q/14149/5760) have lots of useful information and advice. I am recommending closing this question.

Comment: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2585/what-is-the-optimal-ratio-of-used-credit-to-credit-limit-for-your-credit-score or this one.

Answer (score 1):

With the amount of information you have shared with us, the answer would be:

around 9%, ideally <= 1%.

It really depends on your specific situation and there is no one answer.